# how to specify which object to post in rails from the form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am creating an object of `purchase_package` in `touch_books_controller` then rendering a `build_purchase_package` form.

touch_books_controller.rb

```
         if @@wizard == true
           create_pricings(@touch_book)
           format.html { render :build_purchase_package }
         else
           format.html{ render :show}
         end

         def create_pricings(touch_book)
           @price = Pricing.new(touch_book_id: @touch_book.id)
           @price.save!
           @purchase_package = PurchasePackage.new
         end

         def build_purchase_package
           @@wizard = false
         end
```

the form will post to the `create` action in the `purchase_package_controller`

form

```
<%= simple_form_for(@purchase_package, wrapper: :vertical_input_group,
  wrapper_mappings: {
    check_boxes: :horizontal_radio_and_checkboxes,
    radio_buttons: :horizontal_radio_and_checkboxes,
    file: :horizontal_file_input}) do |f| %>
  <% if @purchase_package.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@purchase_package.errors.count, "error") %> 
        prohibited this touch_book from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
        <% @purchase_package.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
          <br/>
          <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

<% if !(@price.nil?) %>

<%= hidden_field_tag :price_id, @price.id %>

<% end %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <br/>
    <%= f.label 'Select one' %>
    <br/>
    <input id="new" type="radio" value="new" checked="checked"/>New
    <br/>
    <input id="existing" type="radio" value="new" />Existing
    <br/>
    <br/>

    <div class="existing" style="display: none">
      Choose existing package
      <%= f.collection_select :id, PurchasePackage.order(:id), :id, :title%>
      <%#*post the package selected from the dropdown above%>
      <br/>
      <br/>
    </div> 

    <div class="new">
      <%= f.input :title %>

      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <%= f.input :price_tier_id %>

      <br/>
      <br/>

      <br/><br/>
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-5">  
            <%= f.input :start_date %>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-5">  
            <%= f.input :end_date %>
          </div>

          <br/>
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <%= f.input :iap_product_identifier %>     
          </div>
      </div>

          <br/>
          <%= f.input :published %>
    </div>

        <%= simple_fields_for(@touch_book) do |t| %>
          <%= t.input :previewable_pages %>
        <%end%>
        <br/>

        <div class="submit-btn">
          <%= f.submit :Submit, class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
        </div>

  <%end%>
```

i want to post an existing package that the user selects from the dropdown in the form.

Comment: One thing to bear in mind is that you do not post **objects** from the form, you simply post **parameters**, ie simple bits of text.  Usually if you want a user to select a package then you would have a select whose name is "package_id", or perhaps "purchase_package[package_id]", if "package_id=" is a method you want to call on a PurchasePackage object, back in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

```
@@wizard == true
```

Why are you using a class variable? It will have no precedent in your Rails app flow

---

**Controller**

I feel your entire flow to be inefficient and cumbersome; you're calling controller actions which have nothing to do with the current object, which is why you're getting confused I think.

For example...

> object of `purchase_package` in `touch_books_controller` then rendering a `build_purchase_package`

Why are you rendering a `purchase_package` in two separate controllers?

--

You'd be best using something like the following:

```
#app/models/package.rb
class Package < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :purchases
end

#app/models/purchase.rb
class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :package
end
```

This is *only* an example; I tell everyone (especially beginners) that since Rails is **object** orientated, you need to think about functionality from the objective perspective.

Your problem is your object (`purchase_package`) should really be created in a `PurchasesController`, allowing you to keep its code entirely within its own scope.

Whilst this may **not** be the entire case (you may have your reasons for breaking apart the functionality), it seems, from your use of a `@@class_variable`, and your inability to pass certain data through your form, that you're experiencing an [antipattern](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?AntiPattern).

--

> the form will post to the create action in the purchase_package_controller

As such, if you re-aligned your system somewhat, you'd be able to get it working:

```
#app/controllers/packages_controllers.rb
class Packages < ApplicationController
   def new
       #logic here for touch_book
       @purchase = Purchase.new
       @package = @purchase.build_package
   end

   def create
      @purchase = Purchase.new
      @package = @purchase.new package_params 
   end

   private

   def package_params
      params.require(:package).permit(:x, :y, :z)
   end
end

#app/views/packages/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @package do |f| %>
   <%= f.collection_select :purchase_id, PurchasePackage.order(:id), :id, :title %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

This is not the answer, but hopefully should show you how a conventional process works.

Currently, your system is focused around functionality. As a result, it's haphazard and incompatible; if you focus on creating & populating *objects*, you'll have the opportunity to create a simple & efficient flow.

---

If you update / comment with more specifics, I'll gladly update my answer.